# "error: could not spawn fsmonitor--daemon in the background" when I stage Changed in Git GUI

Tags: git

When I stage Changed in Git GUI, it raised an index error:

```
Updating the Git index failed.  
A rescan will be automatically started to resynchronize git-gui.

error: could not spawn fsmonitor--daemon in the background
```

[image: error graph]

I can not find the reason and solution for this.

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_fsmonitor_watchman

Answer (score 0):

That should be addressed With Git 2.36 (Q2 2022), with a built-in improved `fsmonitor`.

See [commit a3dfe97](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a3dfe97f418762ccf1d0601c5cce40c77046d4fc), [commit 26b9f34](https://github.com/git/git/commit/26b9f34ab32b66a6387dc5ab3c773d3d4cd86685), [commit b05880d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b05880d357c6dadba8d1d7943f4782fc25e06999), [commit 50c725d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/50c725d6b6f52b1c7fc4940c092d7f205cb99583), [commit ad2b54e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ad2b54e3e89d715a283a3c3ab6262c9bed8cb3a1), [commit 86f7433](https://github.com/git/git/commit/86f7433f9711012fcd9857974fc43dfd693b0aa9), [commit 8aa0209](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8aa020970195f49c369eeff9bf22079002e3454b), [commit 369f0f5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/369f0f54ff92fe321e8c7c2d2372e0eb31f77303), [commit 08894d3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/08894d334969011394dee7ab1dde63176fc51830), [commit a00cdff](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a00cdff81a2d578405cf0f68072da07eee462b93), [commit 148405f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/148405fb27980a63bb532d11f9ab242280052355), [commit dd77cf6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dd77cf61a1a2fbf52c94d0cd986d555ad2ba8a4b), [commit 518a522](https://github.com/git/git/commit/518a522f405ddc51d289192718864f1c784afc6f), [commit 65723b3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/65723b305ad431f0cc1161c1e98346a2ec3152f2), [commit 5ff01b1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5ff01b1f1e8e42805bdf98cb0bd3277d18543b07), [commit 1448edf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1448edfb5115c947e377d650e02f8a3ab7fa7b93), [commit bec486b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bec486b9c13c51b7eca0231ed4b7dac75deaf6a6), [commit aeef767](https://github.com/git/git/commit/aeef767a4155f55233338928f705a3e9986fe2bf), [commit 0ae7a1d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0ae7a1d9ab086330c4f7d86f8b421cd974416848), [commit c284e27](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c284e27ba77ee385d322bb90aeb2284bf52c014b), [commit 9dcba0b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9dcba0ba08d0e843eda1f141c99c72e0aa67811f), [commit f67df25](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f67df2556f372f6095270bf870f32ff84def2e4b), [commit 62c7367](https://github.com/git/git/commit/62c7367133e081973e27b7d53e812103fc7ad6d9), [commit abc9dbc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/abc9dbc0c17fb8ad894162517296c1177a7eb7ff), [commit 16d9d61](https://github.com/git/git/commit/16d9d6175b53ca6197831da78ca8fb0dedb961b6), [commit 3248486](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3248486920d0bfc5584747dc7af8414d05282191), [commit 9c307e8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9c307e8afd930485a8409cadf8cc7065512d9845), [commit 1e0ea5c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1e0ea5c4316d2241dd76ef430a2779db9a097dfb), [commit d2bd862](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d2bd862e7a4a791d88740cc81aad14cdcd90dd2c), [commit 974c1b3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/974c1b398711b8782c01bbd3aec959a458296da8) (25 Mar 2022) by [Jeff Hostetler (`Jeff-Hostetler`)](https://github.com/Jeff-Hostetler).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 439c1e6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/439c1e6d5d8ad4d1134fc6ff5e514d28ff9ecac4), 04 Apr 2022)</sup>

> ### [`fsmonitor--daemon`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b05880d357c6dadba8d1d7943f4782fc25e06999): use a cookie file to sync with file system
>
> <sup>Co-authored-by: Kevin Willford</sup>
> <sup>Co-authored-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff Hostetler</sup>

> Teach `fsmonitor--daemon` client threads to create a cookie file inside the `.git` directory and then wait until FS events for the cookie are observed by the FS listener thread.
>
> This helps address the **racy nature of file system events** by blocking the client response until the kernel has drained any event backlog.
>
> This is especially important on MacOS where kernel events are only issued with a limited frequency.
> See the `latency` argument of `FSeventStreamCreate()`.
> The kernel only signals every `latency` seconds, but does not guarantee that the kernel queue is completely drained, so we may have to wait more than one interval.
> If we increase the latency, the system is more likely to drop events.
> We avoid these issues by having each client thread create a unique cookie file and then wait until it is seen in the event stream.